# jQuery centering div to window vertically resizing issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using this method to center a div vertically on my page:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    $('.container').css({
        top : ($(window).height() - $('.container').outerHeight()) / 2
    });
});
$(window).resize();
```

But the code doesn't work initially. I couldn't figure out what was going on until I tried physically resizing the window while the page is loading. As soon as I physically resize the browser window, the div centered immediately. Any way around this? Why is that happening in the first place?

Thanks!

Comment: When is the code being run? You need to wait until the DOM is ready, at least.

Comment: You probably want to wrap the `$(window).resize()` function call in a `$(document).ready()` wrapper.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to run this code on load as well as on resize

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.container').css({
        top : ($(window).height() - $('.container').outerHeight()) / 2
    });


    $(window).resize(function() {
        $('.container').css({
            top : ($(window).height() - $('.container').outerHeight()) / 2
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The way I accomplished similar code is to define a helper function that centers the div (in the jquery onDocumentReady):

```
$(function () {

    function _centerDiv() {
        $('.container').css({
            top : ($(window).height() - $('.container').outerHeight()) / 2
        });
    }

    _centerDiv();
}
```

I then hooked into the window's resize event:

```
    $(window).resize(function () {
        _centerDiv();
    }
```

When you want to programmatically trigger it (either on-load in the document ready, as above, or to any other event, just call the helper function.

John

Answer (score 1):

Check this [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/aruyiy/1/edit)

I added positioning:

```
 position: 'absolute'
```